# Why gap lock is needed in equality clause

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

```
SELECT * FROM child WHERE id = 100;
```

If id is not indexed or has a nonunique index, the statement does lock the preceding gap. According to mysql documentation.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks

Why is gap lock needed here. Record lock on index with id = 100 will lock all inserts, updates, deletes to table for id=100.

So no phantom reads even if there are multiple rows with id=100. Why gap lock in this case?

Comment: A (row) lock on a row with `id=100` will prevent the insert of another row with `id=100` if and only if it is a unique index (because then this row already exists and cannot be inserted again anyway).

Comment: Row lock is a Record lock which is actually an index record lock, so index with value 100 will be locked. No more rows can be inserted for index=100.

Comment: If you hold a lock on row 10 in the non-unique `id`-index, why would it prevent me from updating primary key row 8 to `id=100` and add it as row 9 to the `id`-index? If it is a unique index, this is not allowed (and that's why there is no gaplock). You could of course check index-row 10 first if it is locked and if it has the same id as new row 9. But then someone else might asked: why don't we use a gaplock? And before you ask: yes, other transaction systems exist. But MySQL does it this way.

Comment: @Solarflare but in this way, doesn't mysql need to lock the entire table to prevent any records be updated to id = 100? why just lock 'the preceeding gap' ?

Comment: @Nowhy If you try to update the id, MySQL needs to insert it into the index at "id=100". So first check: is there a lock on the row I want to update? No. Then: is there a lock where I want this row to be? Yes -> Lock handling

Comment: Because id is non-unique, you can't lock all records with "id=100" by only placing record locks on existed records. In that case, other transactions can still insert a new record with id=100.